# Performing side-effects in Vavr

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, pattern-matching, vavr

I'm going through [Vavr Usage Guide](http://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs)'s section about performing side-effects with Match and other "syntactic sugar" as they call it.  Here is the example given there:

```
Match(arg).of(
    Case($(isIn("-h", "--help")), o -> run(this::displayHelp)),
    Case($(isIn("-v", "--version")), o -> run(this::displayVersion)),
    Case($(), o -> run(() -> {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(arg);
    }))
);
```

and then it goes into discussing how `run` should not be run outside of lambda body, etc.

IMHO, something was lacking in the explanation to give me full clarity, i.e. is `run` an existing method on some Vavr interface (which I couldn't find) or should it be my own method in the surrounding code base?

So I endeavored and spelled out the above example just slightly to be something that I can run and see the results of it:

```
@Test public void match(){

String arg = "-h";

        Object r = Match(arg).of(
                Case($(isIn("-h", "--help")), o -> run(this::displayHelp)),
                Case($(isIn("-v", "--version")), o -> run(this::displayVersion)),
                Case($(), o -> run(() -> {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(arg);
                }))
            );

        System.out.println(r);
    }

    private Void run(Supplier<String> supp) {
        System.out.println(supp.get());
        return null;}

    private String displayHelp() {return "This is a help message.";}
    private String displayVersion() {return "This is a version message.";}
```

Could someone please confirm that I'm on the right track with how this was envisioned to function by Vavr's designers or did I totally go off on a tangent in which case I'd appreciate some guidance as to how it should be.

Thank you in advance.

**Updated:**

```
import static io.vavr.API.run;

    @Test public void match1() {

            String arg = "-h";

            Object r = Match(arg).of(
                    Case($(isIn("-h", "--help")), o -> run(this::displayHelp)),
                    Case($(isIn("-v", "--version")), o -> run(this::displayVersion)),
                    Case($(), o -> run(() -> {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(arg);
                    }))
                );

            System.out.println("match: " +r);
        }

        //private Void run(Supplier<Void> supp) {supp.get();}

        private void displayHelp() {System.out.println("This is a help message.");}
        private void displayVersion() {System.out.println("This is a version message.");}
```

Comment: Not sure what IDE are you using but in case it's Eclipse, you can set up code completion for automatic imports through _Preferences_ -> _Java/Editor/Content Assist/Favorites_ -> _New Type..._ -> `io.vavr.API`

Comment: Yes, I'm using Eclipse, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the documentation could be enhanced by mentioning the `import static io.vavr.API.run;` - it's not obvious otherwise (and implicitly reminiscent of `Runnable`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [`io.vavr.API.run`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2). According to the Javadoc, you're supposed to import the basic VAVR functionality via

```
import static io.vavr.API.*;
```

The `run` function calls a `Runnable` (a function `() -> void`) once and returns `(Void)null`. It's used because

```
Case($(isIn("-h", "--help")), o -> this.displayHelp())
```

does not work when `displayHelp()` is `void`, since `void` isn't a well-behaved type in Java. Specifically, `Supplier<void>` and `Function<?, void>` do not work. Additionally,

```
Case($(isIn("-h", "--help")), this.displayHelp())
```

would execute `displayHelp()` *before* the match, so the matching is useless. This rules out all three (ignoring argument number) overloads of `Case`. `run` fixes this, because `Supplier<Void>` and `Function<?, Void>` *are* possible, and taking a `Runnable` means the action can be deferred until the argument to `Case` is needed.

Comment: Ah, so if I am understanding you correctly what you suggesting is that my initial rendition is superfluous as I re-implemented the existing `io.Vavr.API.run() ` and instead the code should be something like in `match1()` method (see question update)? And the side-effect producing methods are strictly for side-effects, no return value from them is expected?

Comment: You’re new code is correct, but there is no reason not to have a return value. If there is no return value (which is undesirable, since it implies side effects) run is used to get around Java’s irregularities. If there is a return value (which is desirable, and is the usual case), just don’t use run.